# Powershell script can't execute Register-ScheduledJob as a Azure Resource Manager CustomScriptExtension

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

I have an deployment template for an azure virtual machine scale with this extensionProfile:

```
"extensionProfile": {
    "extensions": [
      {
        "name": "customScript",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "properties": {
          "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
          "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
          "settings": {
            "fileUris": [
              "[concat(parameters('customInstallScriptLocation'), parameters('customInstallScriptFileName'))]"
            ]
          },
          "typeHandlerVersion": "1.8",
          "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
          "protectedSettings": {
            "commandToExecute": "[concat('powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File \"', parameters('customInstallScriptFileName'), '\" -adminUsername ', parameters('adminUsername'), ' -adminPassword ', parameters('adminPassword'))]"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

When deploying the vmss the custom script is executed, commands like Invoke-WebRequest and Start-Process work without a problem. But Register-ScheduledJob doesn't work. When I connect to the remote desktop and run this install script manually everything works properly.

This is the code that fails when not running it manually:

```
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -AtStartup -RandomDelay 00:00:45
Register-ScheduledJob -Trigger $trigger -FilePath $installDir\natPuncherStartupScript.ps1 -Name NPSSOnStartup >> $log
logAndClearErrors $true
```

The error is:

```
Register-ScheduledJob : An error occurred while registering scheduled jobdefinition NPSSOnInstall to the Windows Task Scheduler.  The Task Scheduler error is: (32,4):UserId:.
```

I also tried:

```
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -AtStartup -RandomDelay 00:00:45
Register-ScheduledJob -Credential $credential -Trigger $trigger -FilePath $installDir\natPuncherStartupScript.ps1 -Name NPSSOnStartup >> $log
logAndClearErrors $true
```

But now an error shows that the username/password is invalid. Also when running this manually from remote desktop this works fine.

What am I missing? Why can't I schedule a job from a customscriptextension?

Comment: Are you meaning that when you specify `-Credential` in `Register-ScheduledJob` and deploy your ARM template, then you would get an error : "username/password is invalid" ? How did you get the `$credential` for Credential?

Comment: `$adminPasswordSecure = ConvertTo-SecureString $adminPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($adminUsername, $adminPasswordSecure)`

Comment: I use the code from my previous comment to create my credential object, $adminUsername and $adminPassword are passed from the customScriptExtension.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have it login as LocalSystem account if you want to have the vmextension register it.

```
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $jobname -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -RunLevel Highest -User "System" -Settings $settings
```

[Stackoverflow link of this issue I had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46329875/trying-to-use-azure-custom-script-extension-to-run-a-background-job-or-a-powersh)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I could reproduce the errors you encountered by using `Register-ScheduledJob`.

From the official document about [Register-ScheduledJob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/PSScheduledJob/Register-ScheduledJob).

> **-Credential**
>
> Specifies a user account that has permission to run the scheduled job. The default is the current user.

I assumed that this issue is possibly casued by the user account that runs this scheduled job. After some trials, it could work as expected on my side and the scheduled job could be registered to my Azure VM by using ARM template. Here is the core command, you could refer to it.

```html
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -AtStartup -RandomDelay 00:00:45
$pwd= ConvertTo-SecureString “{your-vm-adminPwd}” -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (“{your-vm-adminName}”, $pwd)
Register-ScheduledJob -Trigger $trigger -FilePath $installDir\start1.ps1 -Name bruceScheduledJob -Credential $credential -Authentication CredSSP
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With your code it still doesn't work from the customScriptExtension. I've used my vm adminUsername and password as credentials, but without the domain name or computername. When my install script is called by the customScriptExtension the `whoami` command returns `nt authority\system`, from the remote desktop it returns `myDomain\MyAdminUsername`.

Do I need to specify a full username because the script is executed by a user from a different domain? And if so, how can I request it? I'm deploying a virtual machine scaleset and each vm will have a different name

Comment: I have checked the official [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/psscheduledjob/register-scheduledjob#example-4-create-scheduled-jobs-on-remote-computers) about creating a scheduledjob on the remote computer. After I specified `Register-ScheduledJob` with the parameter `-Authentication CredSSP`, then the scheduledjob could be registered successfully. For adminUsername, I have tested both the single username and the username combined with the computer name. You could test it on your side.

Answer (score -2):

I spent HOURS with the same problem and did not want to provide User/Password info in the script and other solutions failed. This PowerScript line finally worked (executes the batch command *YourCommand*):

```
&schtasks /create /tn YourTaskName /sc onstart /tr YourCommand /NP /DELAY 0001:00 /RU SYSTEM
```

Comment: Whilst the above may solve the problem, it's not using native PowerShell commands in line with the author's code